# Multiple File Writing Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, file-io

I am trying to process multiple file writing commands (to seperate files) without hanging the UI.

To put my question in context, imagine the following

1. My main application looks like a file manager. It currently sees 10 files each of about 5MB in size. (Don't worry about how this list works etc.)
2. When I select one file item, I want it to immediately start copying/duplicating the file onto another location on the SD card. Typically this should take a few seconds
3. I want to be able to select a second, or a third etc. file immediately after the first. At the end of everything, all the files which I selected will be duplicated. So I could, for example click 5 files within 5 seconds, but all the copying actions takes a minute.

At this moment two options have come to my mind:

The first is to simply put the file writing commands of each file in a seperate thread. Pseudocode will look like this

```
Onclick
   new Thread()
      write file
```

If this works, there can be scenarios where I have 10 threads running simultaneously, writing to 10 seperate files. I would like to know if anyone has done this before, and what I should be looking out for

The second option, of course, is if there is already a certain data structure/known methods that can address this problem. Some sort of a pending queue system that gets larger as I add requests, but gets smaller as the system writes the data away.

Comment: Have a look through [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). More specifically, the **Handling Concurrency** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure how the SD-card works, but I can tell you that trying to write in parallel to a single hard disk is a bad idea because it will actually slow down the performance compared to a sequential write.

You may want to try using an `ExecutorService` and measuring the performance with different thread counts but I'm afraid you will end up having to implement a queue with a single thread taking the queued files and writing them one by one.

Comment: The reason parallel writes to a hard drive slow things down is that the read/write head has to keep moving to different parts of the drive. An SD card doesn't have moving parts (at least nothing above the atomic scale). That's not to say that parallel writes to an SD card won't slow things down (I don't know one way or another); just that if they do, it's for a reason that has nothing to do with hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an AsyncTask class that simply copies a given file over.  Each time a file is selected, create a new instance of that class for the selected file.  The thread management built into Android for AsyncTask is well balanced and should handle this use case nicely.  It will be easy to provide feedback for progress and completion using the built-in AsyncTask methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the classes in java.util.concurrent are what you need; specifically the [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) class to create a [ThreadPoolEecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). It has the benefit of accepting as many tasks as the user clicks but limiting the number of threads to some limit you specify. (Spawning threads without limit can be a problem, slowing down not only each other but the UI as well.)

Comment: With one SD-card, a good limit on the number of threads would be 1.

Comment: @MartinJames - That might be best, but I would recommend profiling rather than making such an assumption. For instance, Android supports multicore processors as of 3.0, and who knows, perhaps there are SD cards (and devices to plug them into) that support multiple data paths.

Comment: @Tudor above also suggested that parallel writes to an SD card might be counter-intuitive. Personally, I also prefer to keep things to a single thread (in this case main + the executor thread), rather than have multiple threads that I cannot keep track of.

Thanks for your inputs, I will be trying it out with ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor() and see how it goes